# WaterfallDialog, fire the first step without the user sending any message. C#

Tags: c#, botframework

I want the first step of the WaterfallDialog to prompt when the class is called. Right now to only do this is to use the **OnMembersAddedAsync** method which sends like a welcome message. Which is not I needed.

I want the **StartConversation** to automatically fire when the class is called.

```
   public class HomeOfficeDialogV3 : ComponentDialog
    {
        private readonly StateAccessor _StateAccessor;
        private readonly DirectlineApi _TokenReq;
        private readonly IndicatorDelay _IndicatorDelay;
        private UserDataExtractedDto _UserDataExtractedDto;

        public HomeOfficeDialogV3(StateAccessor userState)
        {
            _StateAccessor = userState;
            _TokenReq = new DirectlineApi();
            _IndicatorDelay = new IndicatorDelay();
            var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                StartConversation,

            };
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), waterfallSteps));
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new ChoicePrompt(nameof(ChoicePrompt)) { Style = ListStyle.SuggestedAction });
            AddDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(nameof(ConfirmPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new NumberPrompt<int>(nameof(NumberPrompt<int>)));
            
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }

        public HomeOfficeDialogV3(UserDataExtractedDto userDataExtractedDto)
        {
            _UserDataExtractedDto = userDataExtractedDto;
        }

        public async Task<DialogTurnResult> StartConversation(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await _IndicatorDelay.ShowTypingIndicator(stepContext.Context, 1400);
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt),
               new PromptOptions { 
                   Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Did you know your office space can affect your well-being?"), 
                   Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(new List<string> { "Hello Buddy " })
               }
           );
        }
  }
```

```
        public MainDialog(IConfiguration configuration, StateAccessor userState)
        {
            _StateAccessor = userState;
            _TokenReq = new DirectlineApi();
            _DialogsTurn = new DialogsTurn();
private DialogCurrentDayId _DialogCurrentDayId;

            var waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                DialogsTurn
            };

            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), waterfallSteps));
            AddDialog(new WelcomeDiloagV1(userState));
            AddDialog(new ExerciseDialogV2(userState));
            AddDialog(new HomeOfficeDialogV3(userState));

            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }
        public MainDialog(DialogCurrentDayId dialogCurrentDayId)
        {
            _DialogCurrentDayId = dialogCurrentDayId;
        }
        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> DialogsTurn(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var dialogTurnID = Convert.ToInt32(UserDataExtractedDto.DialogTurnID);
            var dialogEnum = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DialogEnumerator)).Cast<DialogEnumerator>();
            var currentDialog = String.Empty;

            foreach(DialogEnumerator dialog in dialogEnum)
            {
                if (dialogTurnID > (int)dialog)
                {
                    dialogTurnID = dialogEnum.Count();
                }
                if ((int)dialog == dialogTurnID)
                {   
                    currentDialog = dialog.ToString();
                }

            }
            return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(currentDialog, null, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<MainDialog>();
        services.AddTransient<IBot, MainBot<MainDialog>>();
    }
```

```
        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {                                       
                    var token = turnContext.Activity.From.Name;
                    
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                    {
                        var ConversationExistingId = await _StateAccessor.existingConversation.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ExistingConversation(), cancellationToken);
                        
                        if (_IsTest)
                        {
                            _UserDataFromReactWebChat.Token = _TokenTest;
                            _UserDataFromReactWebChat.UserId = _IdTest;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _UserDataFromReactWebChat.Token = turnContext.Activity.From.Name;
                            _UserDataFromReactWebChat.UserId = Int32.Parse(turnContext.Activity.From.Id);                           
                        }

                        
                        var getDialogID = new DialogsTurn(_UserDataFromReactWebChat);
                        var initializeDialogsById = await getDialogID.GetNextDialog();
                        
                        if (initializeDialogsById != null){
                            new MainDialog(initializeDialogsById);
                        }
                        await _IndicatorDelay.ShowTypingIndicator(turnContext, 5500);

                        var isGranted = String.Empty;
                        var userAllData = new UsersAllData(_UserDataFromReactWebChat);
                        var usersInfoFromWebApp = await userAllData.GetUsersInfoFromWebApp();
                        foreach (var i in usersInfoFromWebApp)
                        {
                            
                            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(i.IsGranted))
                            {
                                isGranted = i.IsGranted.ToString();
                            }
                            new WelcomeDiloagV1(i);
                            new ExerciseDialogV2(i);
                            new HomeOfficeDialogV3(i);
                            //break;
                        }
                        if (isGranted == "true")
                        {
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConversationExistingId.ConverstationId))
                            {
                                ConversationExistingId.ConverstationId = turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id;
                                await _StateAccessor.existingConversation.SetAsync(turnContext, ConversationExistingId, cancellationToken);
                                await _StateAccessor.existingConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var Conversation_id = ConversationExistingId.ConverstationId;
                                var TokenGenerated = _UserDataFromReactWebChat.Token;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (isGranted == "false")
                        {
                            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Unathorized requests."), cancellationToken);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Oops! Something went wrong."), cancellationToken);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have multiple steps but I cut it out for this example.

Comment: You've shown the dialog, but what we need is the code that begins the dialog. What have you tried so far? What happens when you begin that dialog in OnMembersAddedAsync?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, I added some codes.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but we still don't see your `MainBot` code which is presumably where `OnMembersAddedAsync` would be. How is `MainBot` running `MainDialog` and what happens if you try to do that in `OnMembersAddedAsync`?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, My mainbot is just for my token checking and passing data to the dialogs' constructor.

Comment: @KyleDelaney, This is the closest to my example but with less complexity [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).

Comment: Okay so am I to assume that you're calling `Dialog.RunAsync` in `OnMessageActivityAsync` then? Why not also call `Dialog.RunAsync` in `OnMembersAddedAsync`?

Comment: Oh no, I ignored it the whole time. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bot is based on the document that you linked to then it will access the dialog stack from `OnMessageActivityAsync` using `Dialog.RunAsync`. You can do the same thing in `OnMembersAddedAsync`.

Comment: Can you explain your answer, please?

Comment: @E.Zeytinci - Do you want me to repeat the conversation from the comments?

Comment: I'm just saying it because of Stackoverflow answer suggestions. I saw your answer in the reviews and wrote this comment because I think your answer is not detailed enough. The choice is yours and absolutely not mandatory.

Comment: Absolutely, I just added the Dialog.RunAsync on the OnMemersAddedAsync method.